# What does the phrase "Simple For Loops" mean in computability theory?

Tags: computability, recursion, primitive-recursion

I was reading a Wikipedia page on **Primitive Recursive Functions** but there is a phrase for describing the simple for loops which I really don't understand. Can anyone explain this to me?

*The Phrase:*
***An upper bound of the number of iterations of every loop can be determined before entering the loop***

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) page

Comment: Instead of Wikipedia, I suggest picking up a textbook or lecture notes.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Can you suggest any in this field?

Comment: There are many resources, but I don't know any of them well enough to recommend.

Comment: ARK1375, t the moment, "simple for loops" doesn't appear in that Wikipedia page.  Did you mean "basic for loop", which does appear there?  (The answers that people have given assume you kno what a *for loop* is.  If not, "simple for loops" is ambiguous; to understand it, you have to parse "for loops" as an idiomatic noun phrase that's modified by "simple".  The phrase doesn't imply that there is something that loops can do that is simple for them to do.  The phrase "basic for loop" on the page includes a link to the Wikipedia page for [for loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop), btw.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia statement is informal and quite ambiguous. For example, let $A(n,n)$ be the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), and consider the following program, where $n$ is the input:

```
x ← 0
for i from 1 to A(n,n):
    x ← x + 1
return x
```

This function is not primitive recursive, although there is a bound on the number of iterations which is known ahead of time.

A better explanation is the [LOOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOOP_(programming_language)) programming languages. Every loop in LOOP runs $x_i$ times, where $x_i$ is a variable, and the number of iterations is the value of $x_i$ before the loop is run. For example:

```
  LOOP x DO
      x ← x + 1
  END
```

is a problem that doubles $x$, and

```
  z ← 0
  LOOP x DO
      z ← z + 1
  END
  LOOP y DO
      z ← z + 1
  END
```

is a problem that assigns $x + y$ to $z$.

A function can be computed in LOOP (using a reasonable input/output convention) iff it is primitive recursive. So if you only allow loops in which the number of iterations is the value of some variable *just before the loop*, then the resulting function will be primitive recursive, and furthermore, every primitive recursive function can be computed only using such loops.

Comment: A bit mystified why this got downvoted without a comment. Haters gonna hate...

Answer (score 2):

This line is quite self describing. Still, let me explain a bit. `for` loops works in a specific range of values. For example: When you iterate over an array, knowingly or unknowingly you known the `length` of that array, which means that you know the no. of iterations your loop will perform.

Take a look at the pseudo code below:

```
FRUITS = ["APPLE", "BANANA", "MANGO"]

FOR FRUIT OF FRUITS
    PRINT FRUIT
```

Above, the `for` loop will run `3 times`, hence you know the no. of iterations before you even start that.

I hope know you understood that line well.